# How to send form data using ajax and php without page refresh and URL path

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, jquery

Its very common question all over the internet but I don't know how to fix this problem. I have a comment system, where users can post comments. The problem is when someone posts comment on the 10th post of the page, by submitting the form they redirect to the top of the page, which i don't want. I want the comment to be sent successfully and the user must be on the same post. I hope i can understand you all experienced developers.

HTML FORM

```html
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
     <img class="p-1 m-0" src="images/" width="35" height="35" alt="">
      <input name="post_comment" id="add_comments" type="text" autofocus class="form-control pl-3 pr-3" placeholder="type somethign" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-form">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="submit_comment" id="button-form">Add Comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#button-form').click(function(){
      
       var add_comments = $('#add_comments').val();
       if(add_comments == '')  
       {  
            $('#error_msg').html("Comments blank!");  
       }  
       else  
       {  
    $('#error_msg').html('');  
    $.ajax({  
         url:"index.php",  
         method:'post',  
         data:{add_comments:add_comments},  
         success:function(data){  
              $("form").trigger("reset");  
              $('#succ_msg').fadeIn().html(data);  
              setTimeout(function(){  
                   $('#success_message').fadeOut("Slow");  
              }, 2000);  
         }  
    });  
       }  
  });  
});  
</script>
```

PHP Query:

```html
if(isset($_POST['submit_comment'.$ansRow['id']])){
    $comments = $_POST['post_comment'.$ansRow['id']];

    if(empty($comments)){
        $cError = "Wrote nothing in comments!";
    }else{
        $comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['post_comment'.$ansRow['id']]);

        $cQuery = "INSERT INTO `qa-comments` (posted_at,updated_at,user_id,answer_id,question_id,comments_text)
        VALUES
        (now(),now(),'".$_SESSION['id']."','$ansId','$qId','$comments')";

        if(mysqli_query($con,$cQuery)){
           // header('refresh:0s');
        }else{
            $cError = "Something went wrong!";
          //  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }

}
```

console erros.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: `$('#button-form').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); ......`

Comment: still same problem, not submitting without page refresh

Comment: No @Junc it should not present the same problem .. take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp#:~:text=preventDefault()%20method%20stops%20the,link%20from%20following%20the%20URL

Comment: I triend the code you sent, but when i pressed the send butotn, did the same function as before. (not submitting without page refresh)

Comment: see @j4g0's updated answer it should solve your problem .. While I always prefer to use the `form` submit event instead of `button` click event for a form

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').on('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault() ... this is the updated code and the issue is still exist.

Comment: update my question also added php query is ther anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You do not currently prevent the form from executing it's default behavior. When you click the button of type="submit" the form get's sent to the page specified in `<form action="some_url"></form>` or to the same page, if that is empty

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#form').on('submit', function(){
    event.preventDefault()
      
    var add_comments = $('#add_comments').val();
    if(add_comments == '')  
    {  
         $('#error_msg').html("Comments blank!");  
    }  
    else  
    {  
    $('#error_msg').html('');  
    $.ajax({  
         url:"index.php",  
         method:'post',  
         data:{add_comments:add_comments},  
         success:function(data){  
              $("form").trigger("reset");  
              $('#succ_msg').fadeIn().html(data);  
              setTimeout(function(){  
                   $('#success_message').fadeOut("Slow");  
              }, 2000);  
         }  
    });  
       }  
  });  
});
```

This will prevent the reloading of the page and execute your javascript instead

Comment: I added the prevention event still not working. and the action="" i wan to be emtpy (i ran the query on the same page)

Comment: my bad, we should actually add the EventListener before trying to react to that event

Comment: You forgot to add `event` to `function(event)` :-)

Comment: don't think it is necessary in jQuery :D

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').on('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault() .. this is the updated code, same problem

Comment: is it still reloading the page or do we have another error?

Comment: @j4g0 yes its not necessary to add `event` you're right :-)

Comment: yes it is still the same, refreshing page by submitting.

Comment: I want to explain you that the insert query is running on the same page (index.php) where javaScripts running. is it possible? and I mention url: "index.php" is it right?

Comment: I feel there must be something interfering, see https://jsfiddle.net/gd7jq9vm/

Comment: yes its not preventing the page from refreshing, I dont know why

Comment: do you add jQuery anywhere on your page? something like `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` see [jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218847/discussion-between-junc-book-and-j4g0).

Comment: You can add `onsubmit="return false"` to the form tag and send your form data using ajax.